# is it possible (and how) to use a non react button to change the state of a react component/element

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

New to react and trying to gently add it to an existing app.

I write the following Jsx code from several sources

```
class BootstrapDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    handleShow() {
        this.setState({ show: true });
    }

    Show() {
        this.handleShow();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>Modal title</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>

                <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>

                <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Button variant="secondary">Close</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Button variant="primary">Save changes</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

then in a `script` section of an html page I write:

```
const e2 = React.createElement;
const domContainer2 = document.querySelector('#modal_container');
ReactDOM.render(e2(BootstrapDialog), domContainer2);
```

Finally in the `body` of the html page I'm trying to set a button like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="e2.Show()"> show</button>
```

The modal never shows.

I well seen the possibility to [add a button](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/modal/) to the component

But I would like to know if what I'm trying to to is possible.

---- EDIT 1

I found a way:

- set the show property of the state to true in the constructor, and
- for the button : `onclick="ReactDOM.render(e2(BootstrapDialog), domContainer2)"`

But once closed, the state remains to false and it can't be reopened.

Is there another ?

----- EDIT 2

I found a (ugly) one, summurized as follow (use a global variable (this is ugly, this is bad, this is the only way I found))

html:

```
<div id="modal_container"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="showModal()"> show</button>
```

script:

```
var gShowModal = false;
let re = React.createElement(BootstrapDialog, { initialShow: false });
let dc = document.querySelector('#modal_container');
ReactDOM.render(re, dc);

function showModal() {
    gShowModal = true;
}
```

jsx:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
        () => this.tick(), 500
    );
}

tick() {
    this.setState({
        show: gShowModal
    });
}

handleClose() {
    gShowModal = false;
}
```

Comment: If you are using react, have it render ask of your markup. IMO the pattern you're using is smelly

Comment: @im_baby I agree, but I'm looking for the less intrusive way to append React to the app. The button exists, I'm trying to keep it. I may be wrong.